# Is there a term for the traced keys or legends sometimes accompanying complicated photographs or paintings?

Tags: word-choice

For example, Howard Chandler Christy's *Scene at the Signing of the Constitution*
[image: painting]

might come along with a line drawing cartoon identifying each famous subject:

[image: key for painting]

Is there a technical term for this kind of cartoon? If not, what's the best descriptive name?

Comment: My first instinct would be to refer to it as a key, similar to what you'd see on a map or the like.  As for a technical term?  No idea.

Comment: Or maybe just a *map*? [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/map?q=map) defines it as *a diagram or collection of data showing the spatial arrangement or distribution of something over an area*

Comment: @bib I always think of maps being geographical. Visual key? On a more humorous note, it reminds me of painting by numbers. Do those amateur/kids painting kits still exist?

Comment: @Mari-LouA, you can even scuplt by numbers: http://www.alecrivers.com/sculptingbynumbers/

Comment: Ooh, that's cheating! Still, that's pretty amazing. I'd call it "sculpting by colours" ironically,  rather than by numbers. The use for clay animation is really good.

Comment: "Cartoon legend" (not to be confused with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hercules_(1997_film))

Answer (score 1):

I've seen it called a **key**.  An example, "Key to Group Portrait of the Company of Merchant Adventurers of the City of York" is [here](http://www.petermennim.com/group-portraits/key_merchant_adventurers.html)